# SKLearn SVM proba threshold != 0.5?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have an SVM model that I trained (SVC(class_weight='balanced')). I use predict_proba() to get probabilities to compute ROC AUC and predict() to get predictions for f1_score. From the documentation, I'd expect (predict_proba() > 0.5).astype(int) == predict(), however this is not the case. Can anyone help me understand why not? Are my f1_score and ROC AUC scores still valid?

```
a = svm.predict_proba(vec.transform(X))[:,1]
b = svm.predict(vec.transform(X))
print(np.mean(b))
print(np.mean((a>0.5).astype(int)))

0.2517116391461941
0.12907772855416835
```

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-probabilities

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in a fact that there is no such thing as "probability" of belonging to a given class under SVM model. It is just not a probabilistic classifier.

What [sklearn does, is it retrospectively fits another, probabilistic model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-probabilities), into SVM scores (distances from hyperplane), so there is no direct correspondence between predict_proba() and predict(). Instead, consider using .decision_function and then threshold of 0 will correspond to .predict()